# Function Overloading Based on Arbitrary Properties of Types doesn't work

Tags: c++, generic-programming, sfinae

In the example below, I need to extract some values. I have an efficient extractor, which can work with builtin types, and an inefficient template that can work with everything. To choose between these, I want to use [Function Overloading Based on Arbitrary Properties of Types](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184401659). Here is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class extractor
{
public:
    static void extract(const bool& val) { std::cout << "Specialized extractor called" << std::endl; }
    static void extract(const double& val) { std::cout << "Specialized extractor called" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
void extract_generic(const T& value) { std::cout << "Generic extractor called" << std::endl; }


template <typename T> struct is_extractor_native { static const bool val = false; };
template<> struct is_extractor_native<bool> {static const bool val = true; };
template<> struct is_extractor_native<double>  {static const bool val = true; };


template <bool B, class T = void>
struct enable_if {
    typedef T type;
};

template <class T>
struct enable_if<false, T> {};

template <typename T>
struct extract_caller
{

    //line 32 below
    static void extract(const T& val, typename enable_if<is_extractor_native<T>::val>::type * = 0)
    {
            extractor::extract(val);
    }

    //line 37 below
    static void extract(const T& val, typename enable_if<!is_extractor_native<T>::val>::type * = 0)
    {
            extract_generic(val);
    }
};



int main(void)
{
    std::string string_value("hello");
    double double_value(.123);

    std::cout << "native extractor for std::string: " << (int)is_extractor_native<std::string>::val << std::endl;
    std::cout << "native extractor for double:      " << (int)is_extractor_native<double>::val << std::endl;

    extract_caller<std::string>::extract(string_value);
    extract_caller<double>::extract(double_value);

    return 0;
}
```

When I build the compiler complains:

```
g++     main.cpp   -o main
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘extract_caller<std::basic_string<char> >’:
main.cpp:50:29:   instantiated from here
main.cpp:32:14: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct enable_if<false, void>’
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘extract_caller<double>’:
main.cpp:51:24:   instantiated from here
main.cpp:37:14: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct enable_if<false, void>’
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

When comment out the extraction and have only the traits printed, I get correct results:

```
./main
native extractor for std::string: 0
native extractor for double:      1
```

On the error listing you can see that for `double` the compiler passes the prototype on line 32, goes to 37 and prints error. The question is, why the SFINAE principle is not applied here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFINAE only works when certain errors (like the ones you have) happen in *declaration* part.  In your case they happen in *definition*.  You have to rewrite your code so that `enable_if` is used in declaration, in your case of `struct extract_caller`.

Comment: Thanks (and upvote) for pointing out the definition/declaration thing, it led me to correct result. But a better syntax than by using `enable_if` in `extract_caller` I got by parametrizing methods instead of the class. Will post the code.

Answer (score 0):

The code I got by fixing the problem doublep mentioned:

```
struct extract_caller
{
    template <typename T>
    static void extract(const T& val, typename enable_if<(bool)is_extractor_native<T>::val>::type * = 0)
    {
            extractor::extract(val);
    }

    template <typename T>
    static void extract(const T& val, typename enable_if<!(bool)is_extractor_native<T>::val>::type * = 0)
    {
            extract_generic(val);
    }
};
```

This can be used as

```
extract_caller::extract(string_value);
extract_caller::extract(double_value);
```