# Function overloading on arbitrary type properties fails when defined in declaration part of a function template

Tags: c++, templates

I have found a great article on this topic [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/function-overloading-based-on-arbitrary/184401659), and on page 10, the authors note two important things:

1. When function templates are overloaded using enablers, the enablers are placed in the declaration part.
2. There is no need to implement the usual dispatcher - a separate interface function that dispatches to the implementation.

Point 1. can be found as this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9556953/735756) on SO. The authors state (page 10 of the printed out article) that it is also possible to use enablers as function arguments, which is what I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22638156/735756) to do, but then the ADL then failed in that example.

Point 2. is relying on SFINAE and reducing the function template set. SFINAE will not report an error when the enabler fails, and deduction of parameters will result with that template being chosen that fits best.

Having said all that, I modified the previous [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22638156/735756):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Type>
struct tag {}; 

struct Atag {}; 
struct Btag {};

template<typename Type, typename Tag>
struct tag_enabled
{
    static const bool value = std::is_same
    <
        typename tag<Type>::type, 
        Tag 
    >::value;

    typedef typename std::enable_if
    <
        std::is_same
        <
            typename tag<Type>::type, 
            Tag 
        >::value,
        Type
    >::type type; 
};

template<typename A, typename B>
typename std::enable_if
<
    tag_enabled<A, Atag>::value && 
    tag_enabled<B, Btag>::value, 
    A
>::type
worker(
    B const & b
)
{
    A result; 

    std::cout << "Btag -> Atag" << std::endl;

    return result; 
}

template<typename A, typename B>
typename std::enable_if
<
    tag_enabled<A, Atag>::value && 
    tag_enabled<B, Atag>::value, 
    A
>::type
worker(
   B const & b 
)
{
    A result; 

    std::cout << "Atag -> Atag" << std::endl;

    return result; 
}

struct test_a {}; 
struct test_b {}; 

template<>
struct tag<test_a>
{
    typedef Atag type; 
};

template<>
struct tag<test_b>
{
    typedef Btag type;
};

int main()
{
    test_a ta1; 
    test_b tb1; 

    auto ta2 = worker<test_a>(ta1); 
    auto ta3 = worker<test_a>(tb1);

    return 0;
}
```

I expected this to work like described in the article:

The enabler tries to see if A is tagged with Atag, and B with Atag or Btag. The enabler *fails* to produce a valid return type in one function template, if it is valid for the other:

```
   tag_enabled<A, Atag>::value && // Check if A is tagged with Atag
   tag_enabled<B, Btag>::value, // Check if B is tagged with Btag
   A
```

Failing to produce a valid return type for one configuration should not be an error: SFINAE. Then the compiler tries another template, and if say B is tagged with Btag, as it is for `function<test_a>(tb1)`, it instantiates a valid function, and uses it.

However, it doesn't seem to work, and these are the errors produced:

```
test-template.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct tag_enabled<test_a, Btag>’:
test-template.cpp:33:33:   required by substitution of ‘template<class A, class B> typename std::enable_if<(tag_enabled<A, Atag>::value && tag_enabled<B, Btag>::value), A>::type worker(const B&) [with A = test_a; B = test_a]’
test-template.cpp:86:34:   required from here
test-template.cpp:27:13: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, test_a>’
     >::type type; 
             ^
test-template.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct tag_enabled<test_b, Atag>’:
test-template.cpp:51:33:   required by substitution of ‘template<class A, class B> typename std::enable_if<(tag_enabled<A, Atag>::value && tag_enabled<B, Atag>::value), A>::type worker(const B&) [with A = test_a; B = test_b]’
test-template.cpp:87:34:   required from here
test-template.cpp:27:13: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, test_b>’
```

It seems to me that, even the whole point of using enablers is to rely on SFINAE, it seems that both function templates remain as valid choices? I mean, yes:

```
typename std::enable_if<(tag_enabled<A, Atag>::value && tag_enabled<B, Atag>::value), A>::type worker(const B&) [with A = test_a; B = test_b]
```

I know that `tag_enabled<test_b, Atag>::value` is false, that is what I am counting on, the `enable_if` then doesn't have the typedef `type` defined. That's the point of the whole principle, to use enablers to produce invalid return types, and reduce the function set.

That's actually what the authors are doing for the `advance` example in the article, the only difference in this example is the fact that the function template takes two parameters, and they are both checked to be tagged somehow. O.o Did I again miss something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFINAE works during template argument substitution (either when deducing types of function templates or of specializations of class templates).

You, on the other hand, have put logic inside a class *definition*. That's too late. It'll only be checked once the template is instantiated and argument types are already deduced and then it'll trigger a hard error.

Just get rid of the `typedef` inside `tag_enabled`. You don't need it, you need only `value` member to pass to `enable_if` (that's where the substitution failure is supposed to happen - `enable_if` will have or not have the nested typedef based on value of its first paramter).

[Then it works.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b83017a3f3b0a0f8)